# Android - shortcut icons in custom list adapter (google play music)

Tags: android, listview, shortcut, listadapter

I'm trying to reproduce the list view on Google Play Music like

[image: list view picture]

but I'm not sure what is the best way to go about loading the options like "Start instant mix" or "Go to artist" upon clicking the button that looks like action overflow in the list view. Do you treat them as MenuItems? If so, what callback method would you use?

The reason I want to use the shortcut in the listview is because I want the user to be able to see related albums that the song is on, which cannot fit in a tiny list view because there might be 8 pictures in total. They are related to the songs in the list view as well, so I suppose this would be my best design choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I reproduced it by making an `ImageView` with an `onClickListener` that loads a `ListPopupWindow` in the ListAdapter. The ImageView src that I used is just the standard menu overflow drawable.

Answer (score 0):

This can be created by using PopupMenu

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, viewToAttach);
```

and inflate the menu xml file by

```
popup.inflate(R.menu.your_menu_options_file);
```

put menu option file in

> menu/your_menu_options_file.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_item_mix"
        android:title="Start instant mix" />
</menu>
```

You get on click listener by

```
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.action_item_mix:
                                //do the action here
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popup.show();
```